# Access collection in an interface in angular 8

Tags: angular, templates, collections, interface, nested

**I have the following interface**

```
export interface  MenuItem { 
    nombre: string;
    url: string; 
    imgUrl: string;

    hijos : MenuItem[];

}
```

**With the data:**

```
[
    {
        "nombre": "General",
        "url": "#",
        "hijos": [
            {
                "nombre": "Sucursales",
                "url": "sucursales",
                "hijos": []
            },
            {
                "nombre": "Distritos",
                "url": "distritos",
                "hijos": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "nombre": "Seguridad",
        "url": "#",
        "hijos": [
            {
                "nombre": "Empleados",
                "url": "empleados",
                "hijos": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**The problem I have is that I want to access the nested collection and it throws me an error.**

```
<div>
    <p *ngFor="let grupoItem of menuItems">{{ grupoItem.nombre }}</p>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let menuItem of grupoItem.hijos">
            <a routerLink="{{ menuItem.url }}">{{ menuItem.nombre }}</a> -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the error is: "Cannot read property 'hijos' of undefined"

The error is in the line:

```
<li *ngFor="let menuItem of grupoItem.hijos">
```

**How do I access the 'hijos' collection?**

**I appreciate your help in advance.**

Answer (score 3):

Second loop was not inside first one. Change template to this one:

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let grupoItem of menuItems">
    <p>{{ grupoItem.nombre }}>/p>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let menuItem of grupoItem.hijos">
            <a routerLink="{{ menuItem.url }}">{{ menuItem.nombre }}</a> -->
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to access the data outside of the ngFor. Try updated code below:

```
<div *ngFor="let grupoItem of menuItems">
  <p>{{ grupoItem.nombre }}</p>
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let menuItem of grupoItem.hijos">
          <a routerLink="{{ menuItem.url }}">{{ menuItem.nombre }}</a> -->
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```